# Increase transform scale by javascript onclick

Tags: javascript

please help me to build following logic,
here is code:

```
<button onclick="zoomin()">Zoom In</button>

function zoomin(){
   var myImg = document.getElementById("img");
   var i = 0;
   i++;
   myImg.style.transform = "scale(1."+ i +")";
}
```

but, because of i = 0 it works only one time.
please tell me solution.

Comment: the problem is that every time you run the function, the var `i` is being set back to 0. Try moving the var `i` declaration outside of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
var myImg = document.getElementById("img");
function zoomin(){
   i++;
   myImg.style.transform = "scale(1."+ i +")";
}
```

declare i=0; outside function will solve you probleem

Comment: Also the handle to myImg should be moved outside the function as well.

Comment: why declare the same variable over and over and waste computational power.

Answer (score 5):

Move the variable `i` out of the function, it needs to be initialised only once.

```
var myImg = document.getElementById("img");
    var i = 0;
    function zoomin(){


       i++;
       myImg.style.transform = "scale(1."+ i +")";
    }
```